# Is there anyway to stop screen-lock while my app is in foreground in iOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, screen-lock

I do not want the user to be able to lock the screen while app is in foreground, even when the user forcefully tries to lock the screen with hardware lock button. Is there anyway to make it function programmatically?

Please do not tell me *idleTimerDisabled* property of *UIApplication* class.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

It does not work for what i'm looking.

Comment: There is a way. Break the lock button.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible using the iOS SDK.  You have no mechanism for making the user unable to do things like lock the screen or not press the home button.